# Regex get each occurrence with newlines

Tags: regex, newline

I have the regex from a sql query:

```
| Steven | 149203948 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Ut eu lacus gravida, lobortis nulla eu, fringilla erat. 
Nullam vulputate vitae lacus quis sagittis. 
Donec elementum nisl vitae arcu pulvinar tristique. 

| Frank | 993847 |
Morbi bibendum facilisis risus. 
Nullam facilisis, lectus nec adipiscing vehicula, urna nisi rhoncus urna, 
at egestas purus nisl a sapien. 
Suspendisse ac sapien ut eros luctus eleifend ac sit amet odio.
```

**Etc etc**

I'm trying to select the "name", "number" and the entire list of "Lorem Text" so that I can create a sql update statement for each lorem phrase by replacing a particular word with another word.

So I could do

```
UPDATE person p
SET p.lorem_text = '
$3 CHANGED TEXT $4'
WHERE p.name = $1 AND p.favorite_number = $2;
```

For all the entries I get back from my query.
The problem is the stupid newlines, I tried using

```
\| (\w*) \| (\d*) \| ((.|\R)*)OLD TEXT((.|\R)*)
```

But it only gets the first occurence and leaves the rest (| Frank | 993847 | etc) as the entire tail end of my selection.

Comment: I assume you intended to escape the third vertical bar in your regex. If so, please update the question. Also, I don't understand the role of `OLD TEXT` in the regex and what you're trying to accomplish which your third and fourth capture groups.

Comment: The OLD TEXT chunk is a set of words that I want to replace with a new phrase, that's the whole point of this.

Comment: What programming environment are you using to do the regex match and what are you using to specify multiline matching?

Answer (score 0):

```
\| (\w*) \| (\d*) \| ([^|]*)
```

The rest of regex is simplified

Comment: Isn't the `\s` redundant with the `.` in the character class?

Comment: it depends. anyway `\s` - spaces, `.` - characters, and `\n` - new lines.

Comment: Actually `.` matches _any_ character, including spaces. Whether it matches `\n` as well depends on whether "multiline" mode is set or not.